# Disable Page Cache to force page load with browser back button

Tags: vb.net, browser, caching, http-headers

I have an asp.net website that is using update panels on the page that i cant get to reload from the server. I have this for the disable page cache on the master page.

```
     Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
     Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(False)
     Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches)
     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
     Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

When I click the browser back button to go back to the page it says the page has expired. The other pages on my web site work and call the page load, the only solution i found but cant use is to wrp the whole page in an update panel, but i can't do this because i have a report viewer on the page that does not work with ajax. If anyone can help i would deeply appreciate it.

Comment: The expired page message from the browser means that some postback data has been sent. Some browser do ask the user, if they want to re-send it, some don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a browser cache problem; it's a postback one. You have to implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern in order to avoid the "do you want to submit again? / page expired" message.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

The classic example for this thing is when a web page has a save button that insert something in a Database. The "Save" button is clicked -> a postback occurs -> code insert a row in a table -> user refres the page (F5) -> postback occurs again -> code insert the same row again.

To avoid the double insert in the previous example you need to redirect when the "save" button is pressed and only then, execute the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your view file in header part:

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
javascript:window.history.forward(1);
//-->
</script>
</head>
```

Inside body tag add this:

```
<body onUnload="OperaReload()">
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
```

Answer (score 0):

To reload the page with JavaScript use the following:

```
window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
```